# Nested queries in geoserver cross-layer filtering

Tags: geoserver

I use the sf:bugsites, sf:roads and sf:restricted demo layers (available in standard geoserver). I want to display only (the bugsites within 200 meters of (any road overlapping the restricted area whose category is 3)). Is it possible to filter features using such a nested query in geoserver?
I tried the following query but its not working.

```
 CQL_FILTER=DWITHIN(the_geom, collectGeometries(queryCollection('sf:roads','the_geom','INTERSECTS(the_geom, querySingle('sf:restricted', 'the_geom','cat = 3'))')), 200, meters)
```

Comment: what does happen? is there any error message in the log file?